# Put select options into js generated html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I generate rows with `HTML` inputs with the code below. I call the function on a button `onclick`.

```
    function addsav()
{
    html  = '<tr id="sav_row' + sav_row + '" class="lerako_group">';
        html += '<td class="left">';
            html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">From address<span class="label_required">*</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<select class="form-control" value="" name="lerako_honnan[' + sav_row + ']"/></select>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';


            html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">To address<span class="label_required">*</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<input required class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="lerako_hova[' + sav_row + ']"/>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';


            html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">Utca, házszám <span class="label_required">*</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<input required class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="lerako_utca[' + sav_row + ']"/>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';


            html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">Átvevő neve, telefonszáma <span class="label_required">*</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<input required class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="lerako_atvevo[' + sav_row + ']"/>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';


            html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">Rendelésszám <span class="label_required">*</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<input required class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="lerako_rendeles_szam[' + sav_row + ']"/>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';


            html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">Termékek neve, mennyisége <span class="label_required">*</span><span class="label_help">ENTER-rel elválasztva, külön sorokban.<br> Pl.: Termék neve - Mennyisége</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<textarea rows="4" required class="form-control" name="lerako_termekek[' + sav_row + ']"></textarea>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';


        html += '</td>';
        html += '<td class="right"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="$(\'#sav_row' + sav_row + '\').remove();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#sav .new-row').before(html);
    sav_row++;
}
```

In the forst div, there is a select.

In sql table, i have a list of citys. How can i put them into this select?

Now, i just simple echo them out in the body, not in a javascript function generated html.

```
<select name="fuvar_hova" class="form-control chosen-select" id="fuvar_hova">
    <?php
    $ertek = isset($_POST["fuvar_hova"]) ? $_POST["fuvar_hova"] : 1;
    $get_gyartok = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT VarosID, VarosNev FROM Varosok ORDER BY VarosNev ASC");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($get_gyartok) > 0 )
    {
        while($gy = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_gyartok))
        {
            $selected = $ertek == $gy['VarosID'] ? ' selected="selected"':'';
            echo '<option ' . $selected . ' value="' . $gy['VarosID'] . '">' . $gy['VarosNev'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line after the append of the html in the function

```
$('select[name^="lerako_honnan"]').append($('#fuvar_hova').html());
```

or change:

```
html += '<div class="form-group">';
                html += '<label class="control-label col-sm-3 label4">From address<span class="label_required">*</span></label>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                    html += '<select class="form-control" value="" name="lerako_honnan[' + sav_row + ']"/>'+$('#fuvar_hova').html()+'</select>';
                html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
```

Comment: That doesnt do anything, and no errros.

Comment: Thanks, its great! I dont know, that this is so simple. I use the chosen plugin on the select, but it doesnt gets it. The chosen is initialized in the <head>, in document.ready.